# How to split row into two rows in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a `data_table` with four columns. I am trying to make up a `SELECT` statement that transforms each initial row into one or two rows depending on a value in `type` column.

For example, when `type = 'X'` row `(a,b,c)` is transformed into `(a,b)` and `(a,c)`, otherwise it is just `(a,b)`.

**initial_data_table**

```
|  a   |  b  |  c  |  type
---------------------------
|  1   |  2  |  3  |   X  
|  4   |  5  |  6  |   Y
---------------------------
```

**query result**

```
|  first   | second |  type
---------------------------
|    1     |   2    |   X  
|    1     |   3    |   X  
|    4     |   5    |   Y
---------------------------
```

**Could you help me tow find out how to "split" rows on condition in a relational way using only SQL?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking a lateral join with some filtering:

```
select v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values (a, b, type),
             (a, c, nullif(type, 'Y'))
     ) v(first, second, type)
where type is not null;
```

However `union all` would work well too:

```
select a, b, type
from t
union all
select a, b, type
from t
where type = 'X';
```